# Breakpoint on Malloc char ***a

Tags: c, char, malloc, breakpoints

I have  a project to finish ...... and for this i need a char ***a to get all the words that reffer to the dictionary names from a text file (for a translator).
My program always breakpoints on the strcpy(a[line][v[i]], p); I'm stuck numar_cuvinte = word_number linie = line

```
while (!feof(dictionary_list))
{
    fgets(buffer, 100, dictionary_list);
    p = strtok(buffer, "-.\n");
    while (p != NULL)
    {

        if (p != "txt")
        {
            nr_cuvinte++;
            p = strtok(NULL, "-.\n");
        }
        else
            p = NULL;
    }
    v[linie] = nr_cuvinte;  // ---------> v[i] = nr cuvinte pe linie 
    nr_cuvinte = 0;// ----->m
    linie++; // --->n
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
a = (char***)malloc(linie*sizeof(char**));

for (int i = 0; i < linie; i++)
{
    a[i] = (char**)malloc(v[i] * sizeof(char*));
}

for (int i = 0; i < linie; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < v[i]; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
rewind(dictionary_list);
linie = 0;
nr_cuvinte = 0;
while (!feof(dictionary_list))
{
    fgets(buffer, 100, dictionary_list);
    p = strtok(buffer, "-.\n");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        if (p != "txt")
        {

            strcpy(a[linie][v[nr_cuvinte]], p);
            nr_cuvinte++;
            p = strtok(NULL, "-.\n");
        }
        else p = NULL;

    }
    v[linie] = nr_cuvinte;
    nr_cuvinte = 0;// ----->m
    linie++; // --->n
}
```

}

Comment: Aside: please change `while(!feof(dictionary_list))` to `while(fgets(buffer, 100, dictionary_list) != NULL)` and read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Wellcome to SO. In fact, this is a question and answer site, there is no question there. Please go through the help text in the top bar to see what kind of questions we would be happy to answer, and also on how to ask them.

Comment: `if (p != "txt")` does not do what you think. It will never be the same pointer.  Also there is no need to mess with the pointer returned from `strtok`, it is a simple enough loop without interfering.

Comment: is `nr_cuvinte` initialized with `0` before entering the `while`-loop? Same for `linie`? Are you sure that `p` in your `strcpy` never exceeds 19 characters + terminating 0?

Comment: `a[linie][v[nr_cuvinte]]` looks like it should be `a[linie][nr_cuvinte]`